# Infinite screen detection without hitting recursion limit

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have written an image detection program that takes a screenshot of the screen and detects specific images, does calculations and reports them back to the user in a Tkinter window. It all works fine apart from I need it to keep running until the user quits the program, but I am hitting the recursion limit (1000) and get the error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. If I handle this error it of course eventually results in a `stack overflow error`.

There is obviously something fundamentally flawed with my approach. What ways could I go about infinitely taking screenshots of the screen, processing the output and reporting back to the user in a Tkinter window?

My stripped down approach is below. Thanks in advance for any advice or ideas.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.callback_time = 1 # Actual time is 1000
        self.num_screenshots = 0
        self.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) # Keeps the Tkinter window above other windows
        tk.Label(text="Number of Screenshots").pack(side="left")
        self.counter_label = tk.Label()
        self.counter_label.pack(side="left")

    def process_screen(self):
        # Do shape detection here
        self.num_screenshots += 1
        self.counter_label.configure(text=self.num_screenshots)
        self.update_idletasks()

    def take_screen_shot(self):
        #self.screen_shot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, self.screen_width, self.screen_height)) 
        self.process_screen()
        self.after(self.callback_time, self.take_screen_shot())

    def run(self):
        def callback(event):
            if True:
                self.after_cancel(self.process)
                print("Call back Cancelled")
        self.bind("<Return>", callback)
        self.process = self.after(self.callback_time, self.take_screen_shot)
        self.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

Comment: What is mainloop, and why not just call everything in an infinite loop?

Comment: Can't you just launch a single thread with `while True: screenshot() sleep(5000)` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake. `self.after(self.callback_time, self.take_screen_shot())` should be `self.after(self.callback_time, self.take_screen_shot)` without the parentheses.